# Sealing, Priming, and Painting a Window

Tags: windows, sealing, repainting, primer

I have a house full of wooden windows with some old flaking paint. The wood is quite solid, the glass is intact and not fogging. I was planning on scraping the windows and repainting them. My question is, should I seal the wood, then prime and paint, or are some of these steps unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First advise is not to use any "sealer" on window frames. Paint won't normally adhere well to wood sealers.  If possible, I like oil based exterior primer, even two coats so your frames are well covered.  The you can use any good latex exterior trim paint.  Remember, prep is very important, and you cannot use oil based primer over any latex, so if you have latex, you must use latex primer or BIN's Bullseye pigmented shellac.